# PHP charset issue while inserting data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a PHP file which inserts $mail and $password in my database. See code below. My php file, my BD and my table fields are in utf-8. So what I do not understand is why the mail I send "Philémon" goes as "PhilÃ©mon" in my table. By the way I know it is not a mail format. It is just for the sake of testing.

My PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require("php/connect.inc.php");

$mail = mysql_real_escape_string("Philémon");
$password = sha1("pass123");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO ENS_MEMBRES (ENS_MAIL, ENS_PASS) VALUES ('$mail','$password')");
?>
```

Comment: What's the encoding used with `mail()`?

Comment: Your database connection might not be using UTF-8? Not the table itself, but the connection to the DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PHP source code is probably UTF-8 encoded; your database connection is probably ISO-8859-1 encoded, it's the default connection encoding of mySQL. That will cause the UTF-8 `é` to be interpreted as two separate bytes, and stored that way in your mySQL table.

Solution: do a

```
 mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

before sending the data; if that function isn't available, use

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");
```

Comment: Hello Pekka.mysql_set_charset('utf8') solved the problem. You rock! I put header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); Why is it not sufficient?

Comment: @user no. That header just tells the *browser* how to interpret the output that is about to come; it has no effect on anything else

Comment: So header(blalbla) has just an effect on what is displayed on the page? Correct?

Answer (score 0):

For users currently experiencing this issue, `mysql_query` has been deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0 instead mysqli_query(procedural) or PDO can be used([refer php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)). To fix this issue for users implementing procedural extension, try this

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

This worked perfectly for me!

For users implementing PDO extension, try the following

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    ''mysql:host=host;dbname=urdbname'',
    "username",
    "password",
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Hope this helps someone out there ;)